# Validate sub json object in form validation laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am sending json object with sub json object to server.I want to validate sub json object in laravel5.1 form validation method.

My object is,

```
    {
    "empType": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Part Time",
        "status": 1
    },
    "salutation": "Mr",
    "name": "Shihabuddeen",
    "employee_code": "EMP1001"
}
```

My form validation method is,

```
 public function rules() {
        return [
            'salutation' => ['required'],
            'name' => ['required', 'max:100'],
            'employee_code' => ['required', 'max:100'],
            "empType.id" => ['required', 'integer'],
        ];
    }
```

Here all other validations are working fine except `"empType.id" => ['required', 'integer']`.

Is there any way to do this validation?

Comment: I just recreated your code and everything seems all right: http://pastebin.com/j2HDDvYC Validation passes. Where do you get this Json data?

Comment: I am using form validation request method but not validator inside controller.Getting this json from form.